# how to use object-Cpp in Xcode

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I created a new cocoa application in Xcode with 3 *.m files (main.m, AppDelegate.m, and projectnameTests.m). 
In order to to use object-cpp, I renamed the 3 *.m files to *.mm files.

Then I get this following error from Xcode:

> "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "_NSApplicationMain", referenced from:
>         _main in main.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

I have never dealt .o files, so am not sure what's wrong.
Please help.

P.S.: I use the latest Xcode, version(6.1.1).

Comment: You only need to change the file that you're going to be writing the C++ code in.  Change back the main.m file back to a single m.

Comment: Thank you for your replying. I know that. I should change only main.m to main.mm to use object-cpp. But I want to know what causes this error.

Comment: I think you misunderstood.  You shouldn't be changing the main.m file to .mm.  Only the file you're going to write C++ code in should you change to .mm

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add AppKit.framework to the "Link Binary With Libraries" section under the Build Phases for your project target, and that should fix the problem.

P.S. Don't ask me why XCode automatically finds the necessary framework (i.e. AppKit.framework) for .m files but not for .mm files, but adding AppKit.framework fixes the issue because NSApplicationMain is defined in AppKit. Adding Cocoa.framework also fixes the issue, likely because it triggers XCode to automatically link with AppKit.framework.

Comment: How you figured this out, I'll never know. Absolutely brilliant. I was racking my brains for an hour until I found your answer. It all started when I wanted to rename AppDelegate.m to AppDelegate.mm.

Comment: Life saving answer!